# If I have a function of two variables, how do I efficiently create a two dimensional array out of the functional values in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a function:

```
def func(x, y):
  return x*y
```

and I am given a list of x and y

```
x = numpy.array([0, 1, 2])
y = numpy.array([1, 2])
```

I want two dimensional array of element wise product of x and y size `size(x)` by `size(y)`, in this case 3 by 2, such that the output be:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 4]]
```

An easy way is to do the for loop

```
output = []
for i in range(len(x)):
   output.append(func(x[i], y))
```

But this process is not very efficient for large array size. Is there any clever way to achieve the same using `numpy array` functions? I am looking for a method that works not just on this particular function, but on arbitrary function of two variables.

Comment: Does your function broadcast? (Your example function broadcasts, but it may not be representative of your real function.)

Comment: Yes, I am only talking about functions that broadcast, although I would also be interested in something efficient for those which do not broadcast.

Comment: `x[:, None].dot(y[None, :])` for your specific example.